# Solve Linear DE with Eigenvalues (Solve a system of ordinary differential equations related to Markov chains.）

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

1 Three states

Let $\sigma_i^2>0, i=1,2,3$. Set $\Sigma:=\operatorname{diag}\left(\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2, \sigma_3^2\right) . \mu:=\operatorname{diag}\left(\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3\right) . Q=\left(q_{i j}\right)_{3 \times 3}$.
The $Q$ matrix has the following properties
(i) $q_{i i}<0, q_{i j}>0, i=1,2,3$;
(ii) $\sum_{j=1}^3 q_{i j}=0, i=1,2,3$.
It follows that there exists a positive vector $\pi:=\left(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3\right)$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \pi Q=0, \\
& \sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i=1 .
\end{aligned}
$$

Define $f(x):=(f(x, 1), f(x, 2), f(x, 3))^T$
Questions 1: Find the general solution to
$$
\frac{1}{2} \Sigma f^{\prime \prime}+\mu f^{\prime}+Q f=(0,0,0)^T .
$$

Hints. Guess the solution has the following $f=e^{\lambda x} \xi$, where $\lambda$ are eigenvalues and eigenvectors to be determined.
Questions 2: Find the solution to
$$
\frac{1}{2} \Sigma f^{\prime \prime}+\mu f^{\prime}+Q f=(-1,-1,-1)^T
$$
with boundary conditions $f(a, 1)=0, f(b, 1)=1, f(a, 2)=0, f(b, 2)=1, f(a, 3)=0, f(b, 3)=$ 1.